# angular-oauth2-oidc CORS ADFS

Tags: adfs, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using `angular-oauth2-oidc` library to connect to ADFS but I get the following error:

[image]

I am using the following code:

app.component.ts:

```
    config.issuer = 'https://myserver/adfs';
    config.clientId = 'https://myapp/';
    config.redirectUri = window.location.origin;
    config.scope = 'openid profile';
    this.oauthService.configure(config);
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument();
```

Comment: Maybe u resolved this? I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the browser was instructed by ADFS (through the absence of- or specific settings for its CORS headers) not to allow loading the `openid-configuration` when your SPA requests it from some other domain (like `localhost:4200` or otherwise).

If possible, you should reconfigure ADFS to send CORS headers that allow it being called from specific or possibly even all domains.

If that is not possible, your only option is to *not* use any `loadDiscoveryDocument...` features from the library, and instead configure all relevant settings that would be auto-detected yourself, manually.